# Determine why these sets are necessarily open, closed or compact where $f$ is a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Determine why these sets are necessarily open, closed or compact where $f$ is a continuous function

$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

a) $S=$ { $x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = -3$ }

{$-3$} is closed thus $S = f^{-1}(\{-3\})$ is closed, the singleton {$ - 3$} is compact but I don't know if that gives that $S$ is compact

b) $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) > 1\}$, $f(S) = (1, \infty)$ is open so $S$ is open

c) $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \le f(x) <1\}$ This one seems tricky since $f(S) = [0,1)$ which is not open and not closed so it doesn't seem to be any of the choices.

Comment: In situations like this (where you're unable to prove some general assertion) it's not a bad idea to draw or write down some explicit functions to test. Here, can you make $f^{-1}(\{-3\})$ non-compact? Can you arrange that $f^{-1}\bigl([0, 1)\bigr)$ is neither open nor closed nor compact (using different functions, if necessary)?

Comment: For $f^{-1}(\{-3\})$, you weren't sure if it's necessarily compact. Consider $f(x)=-3$; what's $f^{-1}(\{-3\})$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger $f^{-1}(\{ -3\}) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = -3\}$ which is what I had above  so I don't follow your comment.

Comment: Consider the special case $f(x)=-3$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

To break compactness, consider constant functions. To break open/closedness in (C), you can consider the identity function!

Comment: by to break, do you mean to not get compactness? and similarly for the (C).  I don't see what the identity function is going to give me. Because It's supposed to be closed, open or compact according to the question.